# request time out occurs, while executing process

Tags: asp.net

I am developing an application in asp.net 2.0, where i am products details from one site to another. But as there are thousands of products to upload, request time out occurs and the process does not complete.

Can any one help me or suggest me how i can avoid request timeout to occurs in between.
my application is in asp.net 2.0 and using InProc session state.

Thanks in advance.

i also set execution time out in web.config as follows:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="3500" maxRequestLength="2097151" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100" enableVersionHeader="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sessionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28vs.80%29.aspx). Similar question was answered [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1143744.aspx).